# How to set up sigaltstack correctly?

Tags: c, macos, signals

I have seen at least three different approaches to set up the alternative stack for *sigaltstack()*. I'm wondering which one is the best approach:

Approach #1

```
stack_t sigstk;
sigstk.ss_size = 0;
sigstk.ss_flags = 0;
sigstk.ss_sp = mmap (NULL, SIGSTKSZ, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
if (sigstk.ss_sp != MAP_FAILED) {
    sigstk.ss_size = SIGSTKSZ;
    if (sigaltstack (&sigstk, 0) < 0) {
        sigstk.ss_size = 0;
        printf ("sigaltstack errno=%d\n", errno);
    }
} else {
    printf ("malloc (SIGSTKSZ) failed!\n");
}
```

Approach #2
(We've been using this for a while, but the memory allocated here shows up in leak detection (`leaks` command))

```
stack_t sigstk;
sigstk.ss_size = 0;
sigstk.ss_flags = 0;
sigstk.ss_sp = malloc (SIGSTKSZ);
if (sigstk.ss_sp != NULL) {
    sigstk.ss_size = SIGSTKSZ;
    if (sigaltstack (&sigstk, 0) < 0) {
        sigstk.ss_size = 0;
        free (sigstk.ss_sp);
        printf ("sigaltstack errno=%d\n", errno);
    }
} else {
    printf ("malloc (SIGSTKSZ) failed!\n");
}
```

Approach #3

```
stack_t sigstk;
static char ssp[SIGSTKSZ];
sigstk.ss_size = SIGSTKSZ;
sigstk.ss_flags = 0;
sigstk.ss_sp = ssp;
sigstk.ss_size = SIGSTKSZ;
if (sigaltstack (&sigstk, 0) < 0) {
    sigstk.ss_size = 0;
    free (sigstk.ss_sp);
    printf ("sigaltstack errno=%d\n", errno);
}
```

Thanks, Ákos
(Mac OS X 10.8.2)

Answer (score 6):

Approach #1 is the best. The reason why is because of location. Suppose you use #2 and your code flow goes like this:

```
void *blah = malloc (...)
...
stack_t sigstk;
sigstk.ss_size = 0;
sigstk.ss_flags = 0;
sigstk.ss_sp = malloc (SIGSTKSZ);
```

Now what happens if you exhaust your stack space in your signal handler? Your stack will grow downwards and interfere with the memory pointed to by `blah`. It can easily happen if you have some shallow recursion somewhere. #3 has the same kind of problem.

Instead, use mmap because it allocates from a different pool, far away from the data heap, and it is a good idea to setup guard pages:

```
char* mem = mmap (NULL, 
                  SIGSTKSZ + 2*getpagesize(), 
                  PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANON, 
                  -1, 0);
mprotect(mem, getpagesize(), PROT_NONE);
mprotect(mem + getpagesize() + SIGSTKSZ, getpagesize(), PROT_NONE);
sigstk.ss_sp = mem + getpagesize();
...
```

Now you'll get a `SIGSEGV` if a stack overflow occurs which is about a billion times easier to debug than random memory overwrites. :)

The reason #2 is counted as a leak is likely a false positive. The leaks tool you are using likely overrides the `malloc` library function with its own variant, which is another reason to prefer to use `mmap` for this task rather than `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with `sigaltstack()`, but I have been reviewing [the man page](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/sigaltstack.2.html). The difference in your 3 approaches seems to be in how to allocate space for `ss_sp` structure member: use `mmap()`, use traditional `malloc()`, or allocate it off the stack.

If I'm understanding the system correctly, then you absolutely **don't** want to do approach #3: allocate from stack. After exiting the function, the stack space will be immediately reclaimed and repurposed (i.e., altered), and will break the functionality of `sigaltstack()`.

So I would recommend traditional `malloc()`. You could go with `mmap()` if you like the syntax. Per my understanding, passing a `NULL` address to `mmap()` is equivalent to `malloc()` anyway.

Comment: As far as my understanding goes, in approach #3 the 'static' storage class specifier won't allow the variable to go out of scope.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice that static qualifier. Thanks for clarifying. It that case, all of the approaches appear more or less valid and it's up to your personal preference. Or are you having a specific problem with a certain approach?

Comment: Yes. We use the second approach at the moment, but the malloc'd memory shows up in our leak detection.

Comment: No, but I'd like to free it that it doesn't show up as a leak.

Comment: How are you diagnosing leaks? Via Valgrind or some other tool? When is the leak reported? Upon program termination? That's what I would expect. It looks like the correct way to clean this up is to save a pointer to the old signal stack context when establishing a new one, swap the old one for the new one before exiting, and then free() that original malloc()'d pointer.

Comment: The leak detector (the 'leaks' command) is called when unloading the last of our modules; and we implemented it as a global static class instance (which gets destroyed on module unload). I'm not so eager to swap out the alt stack; it may cause unwanted side effects. The mmap solution doesn't show up in the leak detection, so we're using that now.

Comment: It seems like using a chunk of bytes declared in the global scope would work just as well (rather than being declared locally in a function) and wouldn't count as a leak.

Answer (score 0):

Your main concern seems to be with leak checking in the malloc case -- if you have an exhaustive leak checker (which requires everything allocated with malloc be freed before you exit).  If this is the case, you can clean things up by remembering the old sigstack to restore it

```
stack_t sigstk, orig_sigstk;

setup_alt_sigstack() {
    sigstk.ss_size = 0;
    sigstk.ss_flags = 0;
    sigstk.ss_sp = malloc (SIGSTKSZ);
    if (sigstk.ss_sp != NULL) {
        sigstk.ss_size = SIGSTKSZ;
        if (sigaltstack (&sigstk, &orig_sigstack) < 0) {
            sigstk.ss_size = 0;
            free (sigstk.ss_sp);
            printf ("sigaltstack errno=%d\n", errno);
        }
    } else {
        printf ("malloc (SIGSTKSZ) failed!\n");
    }

restore_orig_sigstack() {
    if (sigaltstack (&orig_sigstack, 0) < 0) {
        printf ("sigaltstack errno=%d\n", errno);
    }
    sigstk.ss_size = 0;
    free (sigstk.ss_sp);
}
```